# Funcion Load() Jquery me carga en el div pero, no sus eventos jquery

Tags: script

Buen día, tengas todos acudo a ustedes en busca de una solucion, como dice el titulo al cargar un load en otra pagina las funciones(Jquery) que previamente establecí en la pagina dejan de funcionar si esa misma pagina la cargo en una pestaña diferente funciona perfectamente .

este es el script de donde mando la informacion,

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

          $('.eliminarbt').click(function(e){
   var ideliminar = $(this).attr("id");
  $.ajax({
      method: "post",
      url: "carrito.php",
      data:{ideliminar:ideliminar},
      success:function(data){
          $('.tr'+ideliminar).html(data);
      }
  });


                $(this).closest('tr').remove().val('');       
        location.reload();

    });

    });

</script>
```

y este es el script de donde lo recibo

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

   $('.btdeta').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
           var iddetalles = $(this).attr("id");
       var detalles = "divdetalles";

            $.ajax({ 
                url: 'detallescarrito.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {iddetalles:iddetalles},
                success:function(deta){
                    $("."+iddetalles).html(deta);
                    $("."+iddetalles).css({"background":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19)", "width":"50%"});
                }  
            }); 

      $('#'+detalles+iddetalles).toggle("slow", function(){
});

        }) ;


    });


    </script>

    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){



    $('.btcar').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var car = $(this).attr("id");

        var stop = $('#stock'+car).val();


        $.ajax({

            url:'carrito.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data:{car:car, stop:stop},
            dataType: "script",
            async:false,
            type:JSON,
            success:function(deta){

                $('#carrito').html(deta);
                $.getScript("js/probando.js") 
            }

        });

    });  

        $('#carrito').load("carrito.php");



        });

    </script>
```

---

y de aqui donde llamo a la pagina

> $(document).ready(function(){
>
> $('.btcar').click(function(e){
>           e.preventDefault();
>           var car = $(this).attr("id");
>
> ```
>    var stop = $('#stock'+car).val();
> ```

```
    $.ajax({

        url:'carrito.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data:{car:car, stop:stop},
        type:JSON,
        success:function(deta){

            $('#carrito').html(deta);
        }

    });

});  

    $('#carrito').load("carrito.php");



    });
```

> 

---

if(isset($_POST['idupdate'])){

```
  $idupdate= $_POST['idupdate'];
  $cantidad= $_POST['cantidad'];
  $shopCart[$idupdate]['cantidad']= $cantidad;
```

}

```
    // Proceso para eliminar productos

    if(isset($_POST['ideliminar'])){
        $ideliminar= $_POST['ideliminar'];
  $shopCart[$ideliminar] = NULL;


    }

    if(isset($shopCart)){

        $_SESSION['carrito'] = $shopCart;
    }
```

?>

```
            <table class="table">

                <thead>
                    <tr>
                       <th class="th"></th>
                        <th class="th">Imagen</th>
                        <th class="th">Nombre</th>
                        <th class="th">Precio</th>
                        <th class="th">Cantidad</th>
                        <th class="th">Subtotal</th>
                        <th></th>&nbsp;</tr>
                </thead>


                       <tbody class="boddy"  >
                        <?php 
     if(isset($shopCart)){
         $total = 0;
         for($i=0; $i<count($shopCart); $i++){

         if($shopCart[$i] != NULL){

      ?> 
                       <tr  >

                       <td>  <?php echo $shopCart[$i]['sucursal'] ?> </td>
                        <td><img src="img/productos/<?php echo $shopCart[$i]['imagen'] ?>" width="150" height="150"></td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $shopCart[$i]['nombre'] ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo number_format ( $shopCart[$i]['precio']); ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>

                            <form method="post" id="formstock">
                                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $shopCart[$i]['stock']; ?>">

                            </form>


                            <form method="post" id="formcantidad">
                                <input type="text" class="cant" id="canti" name="cantidad" min="1" maxlength="<?php echo $shopCart[$i]['stock']; ?>" value="<?php echo $shopCart[$i]['cantidad']; ?>" style="text-alaing: center;">
                                <br>
                            </form>



                        </td>

                        <!------------- aqui guardan los calculos de los precios--->
                        <td>
                            <?php 
         $subtotal = $shopCart[$i]['precio']*$shopCart[$i]['cantidad'];
             $total=$subtotal+$total;
             echo 'B.F'; echo number_format ($subtotal);

         ?>
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            <form id="frm<?php $i ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="ideliminar" value="<?php echo $i;?>">
                                <button type="button" class="eliminarbt" id="<?php echo $i;?>"> <span class="fa fa-times" value="Eliminar" src="#" style="color:red; cursor:pointer;"> </span> </button>
                           </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php }}} ?>
                    <tr >
                        <td colspan="4"> &nbsp;


                        </td>

                        <td> <strong>Total </strong><br> B.F:
                            <?php echo @number_format ($total); ?> <br>

                            <form method="post" action="compra.php">
                                <input type="hidden" name="total" value="<?php echo @number_format ($total); ?>">
                                <button type="submit" class="btsiguiente" src="#" style="width: 135px; height:40px;" value="Comprar"> <span class="fa fa-check" style="color:green; cursor:pointer;"> Siguiente</span></button>

                            </form>


                        </td>


                    </tr>

                </tbody>



            </table>
            <br><br>
            <br>






            <?php
}else{

    echo '<script>

    alert("Debes Iniciar Sesion Para Poder Realizar Esta Transicción");
    window.location.href="valencia-tocuyito.html";

    </script>';

}

?>
    </article>



</body>




<!-- llama el Diseño del Menu -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="js/ajax.popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

          $('.eliminarbt').click(function(e){

              e.preventDefault();

   var ideliminar = $(this).attr("id");

              $(this).closest('tr').remove();

    sessionStorage.setItem("ideliminar", ideliminar);          

  $.ajax({
     method:"post",
     data:{ideliminar: ideliminar},  
  }).done(function(data){
   location.reload(data);
  });




    });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: amigo primero gracias por responder, Estas en todo lo correcto, hice las pruebas mandando alert y si los datos me los devuelve vació solo , me reconoce el id del button , me tocara leer y ver como funciona el localStorage, aunque por cuestiones de tiempo tendre que apurarme , chequeare localStorage, de ser muy complicado lo dejare como lo tenia antes que por estética no me gusta , hace la consulta del form sin utilizar AJAX si me lo elimina pero no quiero que me haga refrescamiento de pagina

Comment: Hola Steban agrega actualizaciones o ediciones a tu pregunta mediante la opción "editar", no las agregues como respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Espero ser de tu ayuda.

Lo primero, no tienes una capa de persistencia de datos, lo cual al ir de una ruta a la otra los datos son destruidos por lo que te recomiendo que veas un poco de local storage lo cual te ayudara a que tus datos sean persistente en el navegador local, esto quiere decir que si vas a otro navegador o borras el cache del navegador y vas directamente a la ruta dos esta no funcionara dado que los dato se encuentran persistentes en ese navegador concreto y el modo de almacenarlos es en la cache del navegador.

Otra forma de hacer percistente los dato, es tener un backEnd con una conexión a base de dato, que es lo mas comun en cual quier desarrollo web, el ejmplo anterior que te di de persistencia es mas limitado pero puede servirte en caso de que no quieras entrar de lleno en el backEnd.Lenguajes de backend que puedes usar php python java C# javascript por nombrar algunos, base de dato mysql sqlite posgres por nombrar alguno para trabajar con ellas tendras que aprender sql.

aqui puede ver como funcionan los localStorage, que es para que puedas probar tu desarrollo en local.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

saludos

Comment: no entiendo bien tu pregunta reformulala para ver si te comprendo lo que quieres hacer

Comment: buenas noches, mi pagina principal es reserva .php a ver a través de un load() mando a llamar a una pagina por defecto (carrito.php) , en esa pagina tengo el arreglo multinacional ,  y cierta funciones como la de eliminar un productos, actualizar , como el valor maximo del stock,  el punto es que esas dichas funciones cuando son llamada desde el load() dejan de funcionar  sus script, y si abro pagina directamente como carrito.php si me funciona los script,  la única manera que me funcione es mandando las consulta del form con una action y se haga el refrescamiento, que eso es lo que no quiero

Comment: te recomiendo crear un nuevo hilo con el código para ver que se puede hacer, lo que entiendo que con ajax deberías poder, el tema que no veo como lo estas aplicando.

Comment: como asi compañero ? o sea si se me muestra con AJAX el problema esta, la pagina que mando a llamar no me agarrar los eventos JS

Comment: para ayudarte mejor nesesito ver el codigo amigo

Comment: y de aqui donde llamo a la pagina